# how can i get the value of an an auto incremented id as a foreign key in a different table in Laravel inside a controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

In the table called template, I get the id of `staffmembers` by using session. However, I really don't know how I can to it for the table module. I am coding using the Laravel framework.

I also get this error message :

> Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'templates_id' for column 'templates_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `modules` (`moduleName`, `moduleCode`, `year`, `templates_id`)

```
template::create([
  'paperTitle' => $request->paperTitle,
  'markedElementOne' => $request->markedElementOne,
  'scoreOne' => $request-> scoreOne,
  'markedElementTwo' => $request->markedElementTwo,
  'scoreTwo' => $request-> scoreTwo,
  'staffmembers_id'=>\Session::get('staffmembers_id'),
]);

module::create([
  'moduleName' => $request->moduleName,
  'moduleCode' => $request->moduleCode,
  'year' => $request->year,
  'templates_id'=>('templates_id'),
]);
```

Comment: 'templates_id'=>('templates_id')  - here the value is a string and as the error states an integer is expected, so change this to the integer value that is supposed to be inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the template back to a variable when creating.

```
$tempalte = template::create([
    'paperTitle'       => $request->paperTitle,
    'markedElementOne' => $request->markedElementOne,
    'scoreOne'         => $request-> scoreOne,
    'markedElementTwo' => $request->markedElementTwo,
    'scoreTwo'         => $request-> scoreTwo,
    'staffmembers_id'  => \Session::get('staffmembers_id'),
    ]);
```

get template id from that variable to use to create 'module'

```
module::create([
    'moduleName'   => $request->moduleName,
    'moduleCode'   => $request->moduleCode,
    'year'         => $request->year,
    'templates_id' => $template->id
    ]);
```

Comment: thanks. please accept this as your 'Accepted Answer'